# How can I have a translucent background like a watermark with css

Tags: css, background-image

For a desktop I have an image on the right and text content on the left.  On a mobile I would really like to overlap the two (already done via **css/html**).  But I would like to make the image like a 'watermark'.

I tried **opacity** but that makes the text go light as well (which makes no sense to me).

I then tried to make **opacity:0.2** on the parent (with background image) and **opactiy:1** on the child div (with text), but thats ignored.

I know that I can do this with **javascript**, but surely there must be a simple **css** solution.

Comment: I will try it, it looks like it should work.

Comment: I have it working finally,  Its the reverse of the other requirement.